# Keras Conv1d input shape problem, Incompatible shapes: [22,10] vs. [22,10,10]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

I am trying to use a conv1d to predict time series, but I have trouble with the conv1d input shape. My data 406 samples of 10 values in temporal order. The goal is to predict sample N+1 using sample N as input.

Here is a sample of my code :

```py
data_x = data[:-1]
data_y = data[1:]

print(data_x.shape)
# (406, 10)
print(data_y.shape)
# (406, 10)

data_x = data_x.reshape(-1, 10, 1)
# Shape before cnn :  (406, 10, 1)

print('Shape before cnn : ', data_x.shape)
inputs = Input((10, 1))
x = Conv1D(64, 3, input_shape=(10, 1))(inputs)
x = Dense(64, "relu")(x)
x = Dense(64, "relu")(x)
x = Dense(10, "sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs, x)
model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['mean_squared_error'], optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(data_x, data_y,
                    batch_size=22, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

But I get this error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [22,10] vs. [22,10,10] [[node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference (defined at E:/Dev/Python/StockMarketPrevision/mainTensorflow.py:65) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_872]`.

I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Your target is 2D while your network is producing 3D... use some flatten/globalpooling operations after Conv1D

Comment: Ho right of course, thank you !